# High CPU - mysqltuner assistance (wordpress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, cpu-usage

I just migrated wordpress blog to new server. It has some 120K posts.

The problem is It get struck, hang or even freeze during mysql operation.
A single wordpress(without any plugin) create post operation consumes 60-80% of CPU. And when perform 3-5 database operation it goes frozen.
And there isn't any log for slow query.

> System: Ubuntu 18.04 with 16GB RAM, 8 Core CPU, 120GB Disk and MySQL version 5.7.25

Here is mysqltuner and other reports

- Mysqltuner:- https://pastebin.com/ZNYieJj8
- htop:- https://pastebin.com/43f4b3fK
- top:- https://pastebin.com/rTh1XvUt
- INNODB STATUS:- https://pastebin.com/nGrZjHAg
- GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/K2fgKwEv

and current mysql.cnf

```
[mysqld]
# Skip reverse DNS lookup of clients
skip-name-resolve
default-storage-engine=InnoDB

max_allowed_packet=500M
max_connections = 256
interactive_timeout=7200
wait_timeout=7200

innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_open_files=5000
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_io_capacity_max=4000
innodb_old_blocks_time=2000
open_files_limit=50000

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_min_res_unit = 1M
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 50M

tmp_table_size= 256M
max_heap_table_size= 256M

#key_buffer_size = 128M
thread_stack = 128K
thread_cache_size = 32

slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
```

**Edit:**
Initial mysql.cnf variables I pasted above had some incorrect/changed values comparing those of when generating mysqltuner report. corrected thank you @EchoMike444

Comment: your current `mysql,cnf`does not match what we see in MysqlTuner / Htop . innodb_buffer_pool_size in you files is 4G , it seem to be 8G

Comment: your database size seem to be small 2G , can you confirm ?

Comment: how did you migrate the database ?

Comment: mysql.cnf variables I pasted above had some incorrect/changed values comparing those of when generating mysqltuner report. corrected. Sorry and thank you @EchoMike444

Comment: Actually I did not migrate the database as a whole and it was not possible at old server due to limited access. I just created an API and inserted using wp_insert_post() at new wp installation.

Comment: First, make the changes that mysqltuner.pl suggested.

Comment: Missing from the list of links:  `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` after it has been up for at least a day.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS - Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce 90% of cpu cycles used for function every SECOND
innodb_io_capacity=3500  # from 2000 to enable higher IOPS on your SSD devices
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty overhead - count was 3183 in SGStatus
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 277,134
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 778
```

There are many more opportunities to improve performance through Global Variables. Disclaimer: I am the author of web site mentioned in my profile, Network profile that includes contact information.

Answer (score 0):

The "meta" tables in WordPress have an inefficient schema.  [*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) discusses the fixes needed to make them more efficient.

Those fixes will not fix the inherent inefficiency of EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) schema that is inherent in WordPress.